# Form theming a collection widget

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a collection widget in my form. That's displayed like:

Teams     0     player1     inputfield
1     player2     inputfield

I would like to not display the word 'teams' and the '0' and the '1'. 
I've got this block in my fields.html.twig template, but not really sure how to edit this.

```
{% block collection_widget %}
{% spaceless %}
    {% if prototype is defined %}
        {% set attr = attr|merge({'data-prototype': form_row(prototype) }) %}
    {% endif %}
    {{ block('form_widget') }}
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock collection_widget %}

{% block form_label %}
{% spaceless %}
    <div class="hidden">
        {{ block('generic_label') }}
    </div>
{% endspaceless %}
{% endblock form_label %}
```

ChallengeType form:

```
class ChallengeType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('teams', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TeamType(),
                'allow_add' => true
            ))
            ->add('place')
            ->add('date');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'challenge';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array('data_class' => 'Tennisconnect\DashboardBundle\Entity\Challenge');
    }
}
```

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those lables are created in `form_label` block. I usually wrap them in a div and set them hidden when needed.

**Edit:**

There is a better solution :).

Change `collection` section of the `ChallengeType.php` with following

```
->add('teams', 'collection', array(
                'type' => new TeamType(),
                //label for Teams text
                'attr' => array('class' => 'team-collection'),
                //label for each team form type
                'options' => array(
                  'attr' => array('class' => 'team-collection')
                ),
                'allow_add' => true
            ))
```

Now those unwanted labels will have `team-collection` class. In your css file you can set `display:none` for `label.team-collection`. No need to change form theme block definition.

Comment: I do have another question. I have a datetime widget which apparently uses that form_label too. I've edited my initial post to what I have now. How do I fix this so the form label will be hidden for the collection but not hidden for the datetime widget?

Comment: I found something that says I could set rendering options on a individual field like this: http://brentertainment.com/other/docs/cookbook/form/twig_form_customization.html#how-to-customize-an-individual-field But is there a way to do this for a label?

Comment: Yes it can be done. But it is unnecessary and complex. Please follow the edited solution and tell about the result :).